# Is it possible to make a combobox made out of functions

Tags: c#, combobox

i have a class which contains many functions.

is there any way to go over that class, and put a refrence to each of the functions in the combobox, so it will be selectable?

the idea is that when i make a new function, it will be added to the combobox so ill be able to choose it, and perform it.

Comment: Look into reflection..

Comment: How similar are the function signatures?  You might be able to create a list of `Func<>` objects (or list of some small model containing a `Func<>` object as well as a display name, etc.) and invoke the `Func<>` when selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx):

```
Type t = typeof(YourClass);
// public instance methods 
MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var methodsNames = methods.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
// add them to combobox
myCombobox.Items.AddRange(methodsNames);
```

Comment: Don't forget you can use reflection to execute the method as well, depending on your needs: var yourClass = new YourClass();
            var output = type.GetMethod(myCombobox.SelectedItem.Text).Invoke(yourClass, null /* - or list of parameters */);

Comment: Yeah, reflection is a powerful tool.

Comment: do you have any idea how i can show a description of the function?

Comment: It depends on how you want to show them and where you hold them. This, perhaps, could be another question.

Comment: my program is way too complicated to do this. ill just find another way.
is there any dynamic property to functions like description or something?

Comment: As fat as I know there is no such thing, you can try to crete your own wrapper class which could contain description.